# how can a select two tables in mysql using UNION?

Tags: php, mysql

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByVhijs7bMwjUUZQRHpXUHFvODg/edit?usp=sharing

this s my code

i cant select the product_name and price form two tables"herbs" and "fruits" by using UNION
i am a very beginner of php and mysql 
please help me

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM fruits UNION SELECT * FROM herbs WHERE product_code='$product_code' LIMIT 1");
$obj = $results->fetch_object();
```

Comment: try this ((SELECT * FROM fruits ) UNION (SELECT * FROM herbs WHERE product_code='$product_code' )) LIMIT 1

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\products\cart_update.php on line 13   i got this error

Comment: does herbs have column `product_code` ?

Comment: Didn't you say the problem was solved a 30 minutes before you posted this question? What happened in that half hour?

Comment: yes table "herbs" also have column product_code                         INSERT INTO `herbs` (`id`, `product_code`, `product_name`, `product_desc`, `product_img_name`, `price`) VALUES                      INSERT INTO `fruits` (`id`, `product_code`, `product_name`, `product_desc`, `product_img_name`, `price`) VALUES

Comment: problems didn't solved. i can update the shopping cart but can't show the product name and price to count the total price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you to read [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) first.
The `where` keyword should be used for each table. Like this:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE product_code='$product_code' UNION SELECT * FROM herbs WHERE product_code='$product_code' LIMIT 1");
$obj = $results->fetch_object();
```

Comment: my problems was totally solved. thanks for you help again Mr.Barmar

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$results = $mysqli->query(" 
                          SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE t.product_code='$product_code'
                           UNION 
                           SELECT * FROM herbs WHERE t.product_code='$product_code' 
                           LIMIT 1");
$obj = $results->fetch_object();
```

Comment: You don't need the subquery. LIMIT applies to the UNION, not the individual queries.

Comment: i think you right @Barmar